# How to create webhooks through the API for a Shopify App uninstall

Tags: cakephp, shopify, webhooks

I want to create webhook for shopify app uninstall using shopify api in cakephp.

I am not able to connect the flow as my impression is to set the webhook we need some url to be set in a dashboard. In Shopify app dashboard(Shop Partner) there is no setting for that.

How we can notify our own server when a shopify app uninstalls.

Please dont give reference to shopify api..i have been through them completely.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the correct answer but here it is anyway. [Shopify API](http://docs.shopify.com/api/webhook)

You'll just create **app/uninstalled**

There is NO OTHER WAY to do this... so deal with it. It is simple to do.

Comment: How i can create "app/uninstall" and get my server notified when ever there is an uninstallation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the the 'app/uninstalled' webhooks using Shopify Webhooks API

Create an object with 'topic' => 'app/uninstalled', 'address'=> your_url_address, 'format' => (xml/json) and do a POST request to '/admin/webhooks.json'

[Example](http://docs.shopify.com/api/webhook#create)